# Which type of ML can use to learn this type of pattern?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I downloaded a sudoku generator in Python and it creates simple sudoku puzzle that it is always make up of 3 sets (in column 'V') of same numbers vertically as shown below:
[Puzzle: completed, beginning and 3 sets of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jytGo.png)

[Puzzle in Python list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFp4O.png)
Which type of machine learning can be trained to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with a linear dataset or a dataset in which there is a linear relationship between the predictors (input features) and the output, then linear models such as linear or logistic regression can do the trick. Otherwise, if you have nonlinear datasets, neural networks can be a good choice.

I think as per my idea for puzzle solving you need to use `Crook’s Algorithm`.

Because with this algorithm you can solve the puzzle with a few steps.

Also, you can train a model with help of Crook’s Algorithm formulas.

If you want to try the code of puzzle solving I will share a link to the blog where you can get the exact steps of how to program with help of Crook’s Algorithm.

[https://towardsdatascience.com/solve-sudoku-more-elegantly-with-crooks-algorithm-in-python-5f819d371813](https://easy%20way%20to%20solve%20puzzle%20with%20python)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. The link provided is not working, after google 'Crook's algorithm' found the project by wyfok, I use it to solve the puzzle from that sudoku generator I found on internet, it just can't complete the solution but I can continue from there and complete it easily. It lack of the ability of pattern recognition which I think may be achievable by machine learning